# Button takes to wrong location

Tags: java, android

So i am having some trouble with my application, bt3 takes me to bt2 location when i dont want it to, Can someone please explain why?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bt, bt2, bt3;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                    bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);



                    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                            integrator.initiateScan();
                        }
                    });

                    bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, location1.class);
                            startActivity(intent);

   }

                    });



                    bt3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, location2.class);
                            startActivity(intent);





                        }
                    });

                }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
                    {
                        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                        if (requestCode == 0) {
                            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                            }
                        }
                    }


                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

To clarify what each button is suppose to do:

`button1` is supose to start a scan,

`button2` is supose to take me to location1,

`button3` is supose to take me to location2.

Comment: where is the code of the `startActivity` method? Presumably, that's where it probably goes wrong.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: startActivity is part of the base class Activity, provided by Android SDK

Comment: @Pphoenix right, having no experience with the Android SDK, I could not have known that. I've added the Android tag to the question.

Comment: the xml of the 2 buttons?

Comment: @user3639852: Are you sure the two classes location2 and location1 are implemented differently? So you dont just copied code and forgot to change them and now they look the same?

Comment: yeah the problem is with your classes layout not how you change the view...

Comment: One possiblity is that the resource ids are just out of sync after editing the XML. Clean and rebuild fixes if that is the case.

Comment: @user3639852: No I mean with the classes. Your buttons definitely call different classes (if you haven't overrided them with some onClick in your xml, which I do not know). Thus, the location1 and location2 classes can have the same layout, which might confuse. Try to check if their layout is the same. If not, clean and rebuild :)

Comment: @cesztoszule  What do you think that i would of missed that caused this? Im pretty sure that i changed all that i had to as i have done it before i had the scan button and it worked fine.

Comment: Going to upload the code for classes `location1` and `location2`..

Comment: Edit: As i was doing this i did notice that i didn't see the `setContentView`, That was the problem and as both cesztoszule and Pponenix said, If you want to post it as an actual answer ill accept it and all that stuff. Thanks

Comment: Note, Now when i click on the `button3` it now crashes the application, I have searched everywhere but cannot find a useful guide on how to read logcat, If anyone has a good one could they link me it to prevent further issues from me :P

Comment: read logcat ? There should be a logcat tab next to console, if not then Window->Show View-> find logcat (not the deceprated one).. and it should be a tab with logcat.

Comment: @cesztoszule I understand how to get there and see all the errors pop up, I just dont understand what each one means, All i can manage to pull out of it is that its pointing at my `addListenerOnButton();` and `button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {` but i dont see how they would be causing the crash as i have the same code on another activity and it loads fine.

Comment: because you are using it wrong, or implement OnclickListener in the class header and you get the widget id and use a switch, or with new View.OnClickListener() for each widget.

Answer (score 0):

You could try implementing the `onClick` methods for each button in the XML instead, see if that changes anything.